# Why .isNotNull(); assertions fails even though I have a controller class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, pivotal-web-services

I am new to Spring Boot and testing. I am currently studying from baeldung's tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) and I bumped into this error.

[image]

In fact, it passes when I use isNull() method. But I don't understand this because my controller class has mappings and all that. Why would it be null?

This is my controller class

[image]

Or maybe this is not how this test is supposed to be done? But they show it as follows in baeldung

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Best,

Comment: This variable is null as your test doesn't load Spring context. You should setup test as Hiren proposed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the testcases with spring context you need to provide `@SpringBootTest` annotation at your test class (i.e instead of `@SpringBootConfiguration` at your test class `Smoke`). The other option apart from `@SpringBootTest` are as below.

for junit4:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringTestConfiguration.class })
public class YourTestClass {}
```

for junit 5:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringTestConfiguration.class })
public class YourTestClass
```

Where `SpringTestConfiguration` class hold's all the beans you need to autowire. For more details of SpringRunner vs SpringBootTest read the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer Hiren. When I use @SpringBootTest, I get error

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a "@SpringBootConfiguration" , you need to use "@ContextConfiguration" or "@SpringBootTest(classes=...)" with your test

Comment: yes you need to remove @SpringBootConfiguration annotation

Comment: One more suggestion is, if you want to do intergration testing of your controller API you should consider MockMvc as demonstrated in the link I shared in my ansser

Comment: I removed @SpringBootConfiguration annotation. Right now I only have "@SpringBootTest" but I get the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229344/discussion-between-burakhan-aksoy-and-hiren).

Comment: Ok. so the thing is your test class should be under the hierarchy of your SpringBootApplication class. If it is not then you need to provide it as classes argument in @SpringBootTest annotation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assertNotNull(studentController)?